# Collapsible (accordion) Quick Launch in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, navigation, quick-launch

We have a SharePoint site within a site collection. That site has a couple of items in the left navigation, e.g.

```
* Projects
* Employees
* Tasks
```

Is there a way, that if I click on `Projects`, the navigation expands so that there is a subnav like this:

```
* Projects
  - Project A
  - Project B
  - Project C
* Employees
* Tasks
```

If yes? How can I do that? Can I do that only by using the Frontend? Or do I have to use something like the SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Please add SharePoint Version

Comment: Sorry, it's SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 3):

You have and option here:

http://yakovenkomax.com/converting-sharepoint-2013-quick-launch-to-accordion-menu/

It uses CSS, jquery and Master page.

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: That looks pretty interesting, although pretty invasive. Do you know a "native" way?

Comment: I think there is no native mode

Comment: So I'll need the SP Designer in order to add the asset files (CSS/JS). I'll try if I can manage that...

Comment: Yes and you need to update the master page. It is a good thing to learn

Comment: Do you know a good resource on how to update the master...?

Comment: I do not know, but you can find. There must be many. The important thing is that you do not modify the master page original. But you make a copy.

Comment: can this be applied to SP 2010? am having a similar requirement.